# Can I still salvage my water damaged counter top?

Tags: faucet, kitchen-counters

My faucet has dipped significantly due to my old wood counter top wearing down from water over time.

Here's how it looks right now

[image: faucet sinking]
[image: faucet sinking top view]

I went out Home Depot and purchased a countermate in attempts to address this issue without having to spend the extra dollars on a new counter top

[image: countermate]

However, when I began the installation process, I saw this

[image: under the counter]

The instructions tell me that I should be able to install it easily by simplying taking off the water jam nut, putting the metal plate under the damaged counter top and securing the water jam nuts back in.

[image: countermate install instructions]

My question is, given what you've seen, is it still possible to salvage this counter top? Or should I return the countermate and start looking for a new counter top?

If it is possible, what is the course of action that I should take?

Comment: Unfortunately, your countertop is shot. You need a new countertop. Particleboard does not like water and once it gets wet, it's down hill there.

Comment: As a short term fix, you could get a second counter mate and sandwich them, but as noted above, your counter is done for.

Comment: +1 for the bottle of LOC! ;)

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of the countermate is to allow the faucet to clamp onto a wider area of a damaged benchtop. so yes it can help you.

> My question is, given what you've seen, is it still possible to salvage this counter top? Or should I return the countermate and start looking for a new counter top?

If you can maintain a watertight benchtop it's possible. that's more about what's on the top side than what the underside looks like.

Comment: Looking at the picture of the faucet from above, I'd say the top is pretty well shot, too. Installing two of these "countermates" as suggested by Aloysius in a comment on the OP will suffice to buy some time, but the whole thing will need to be replaced sooner rather than later.